# Trouble making SUM Query Import Range function in Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am trying to get a function for a cell on one spreadsheet which will add all the values of the cells of a particular column (Col 7) in another spreadsheet so long as for each respective row a different column (Col 2) = "certain restaurant name". Here is my attempt:

```
=Sum(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("'"Index!C9"'","report.csv!A1!:Z1000"),"select Col7 where Col2 CONTAINS "ADC"",0))
```

It is giving me a parse error however, and I do not know enough about how these functions work together to gather whats wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to query data generated by an "IMPORTRANGE" function, and sum Col 7 of the data subject to a criterion on Col2. You have tried:

`=Sum(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("'"Index!C9"'","report.csv!A1!:Z1000"),"select Col7 where Col2 CONTAINS "ADC"",0))`

Consider these alternatives based on my test data:

- to show the criterion field **as well as** the summed field

> `=query(importrange("<<insert spreadsheet url>>","A1:B5"),"select
>   Sum(Col1), Col2 where Col2 contains 'ADC' group by Col2 label
>   Sum(Col1) ''",0)`

- to show just the summed field

> `=query(importrange("<<insert spreadsheet url>>","A1:B5"),"select
>   Sum(Col1) where Col2 contains 'ADC' label Sum(Col1) ''",0)`

Things to note:

- "Sum" is part of the query; you must sum Col7 or, as in my test data, Sum(Col1)
- You specified "0" as the "headers" parameter in order to suppress headers. However Sum(Col1) isn't a field in the range, so QUERY will display a header "Sum" even though "headers"=0.

  - Therefore, `label Sum(Col1) ''` is added to suppress the header for Sum(Col1).
- In the example where the criterion field is displayed and the other field is "Sum(Col1)" (an [Aggregation function](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#aggregation-functions)), it is necessary to `group by` Col2.

---

**IMPORTRANGE - test data**

[image: IMPORTRANGE]

---

**Query output**

[image: Query Output]

Comment: Excellent thank you for your help Ted! I had played around with it a little after asking the question, and ended up doing this: =IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(Index!$C9,"report.csv!A1:Z1000"),"Select sum(Col7) where Col2 contains 'ADC' label sum(Col7)''",0)). I appreciate your help in getting the solution. Thank you again :) !